# Getting only one div performing an jQuery.ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

what is the proper way to call a specific id or class of a div in another page using the ajax in jQuery? 
my code is not working and i'm sure i'm just not getting the syntax right.

thanks in advance for the help

The code that doesn't work ->

```
   $.ajax({
      url: "includes/content.php",
      dataType: "html",
      success: function(data) {
        var result = $(data).find('.si');
        $("the div i present the content in").html(result);
```

Comment: "in another page"? That isn't going to work. You can only insert content into the current DOM tree when the ajax call is done.

Comment: So what's the proper way of doing what i wanted? i want to call content from another page and present it in current page in a specific div. Regards. ,

Comment: Send request for content to that page and process it using some server side language like PHP on that page. You cannot use ajax to load content from another page.

Comment: @anuragsn7 ?!?! actually AJAX is exactly for that reason.. loading content from another page..

Comment: You mean that I can request another page and take selected part of it only? Looks like I will have to dig deeper into AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are intending to load a certain div into your page, you can use the [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method instead. It let's you pass a selector as a parameter, to only get a certain part of the  loaded page.

```
$('#id-of-element-to-present-the-result-in').load('includes/content.php .si');
```

Comment: your answer was indeed helpful, but leads me to another one. When should i use .ajax, .get, .load? regards,

Comment: @FedeSc Good, and what is your other question?

Comment: `.ajax()` is a general purpose method, that can be used for any Ajax-call. It provides a whole range of options, to fit your specific purpose. `.get()` is a short-hand for `.ajax()` when you want to do a HTTP-GET request. `.load()` is a shorthand when you want to load a piece of HTML from another page, and add it to the current page.